# Remove portion of html (tag) keeping style - python

Tags: python, html, css, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I would like to remove a portion of an HTML that contains a specific string before saving it. The tag contains a person's Name and I would like to remove the entire tag to make it anonymous.

The HTML is:

```html
<div id="top-card" data-li-template="top_card">...</div>
```

and all its children.

I explored using beautifulsoup but could not find a solution.

Is there a way that I can just remove the entire `portion` of the HTML while keeping the style intact?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by "specific string"? If you show your attempted solution, it's easier for people to help you as well.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo, I added a line stating the the tag that I want to remove contains a certain Name.

Comment: Can you update the example to include the name? Or maybe you are referring to the `id`?

Comment: The html contains the data of a vcard. I am trying to keep the document format while making it anonymous. I want to remove the entire top_card portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)to remove elements from using `BeautifulSoup`.

Assuming you want to remove the div whose id is "top-card":

```
>>> html = """
... <div id="top-card" data-li-template="top_card"><div>test</div></div>
... <div>test</div> <div id="foo">blah</div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> [div.extract() for div in soup("div",id="top-card")]
[<div data-li-template="top_card" id="top-card"><div>test</div></div>]
>>> soup
<html><body>
<div>test</div> <div id="foo">blah</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a promising solution.  It looks like the code returns the tag or string that was extracted. How do I keep the original html code 'minus' the tag removed?